# Missing or insufficient permissions with big size array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store a big amount of text (`> 1mb`) but firestore has a limitation on size. So I split the text into chunks like `[text1,text2,text3...]` and tried to upload it but have this error - `Missing or insufficient permissions`.

I tried to upload a small size array (`< 1mb`) with a text chunks and everything uploaded fine. So the problem is not with `Missing or insufficient permissions`

Any solution to such a big text amount ?

Comment: are `[text1,text2,text3...]` stored as different documents?

Comment: no if all text is `sometext` than I split it by chunks `[so, me, te, xt]` and trying to put in firestore

Comment: If it's all in one document you're hitting the max document size limitation (see [Usage limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)). But that doesn't explain the error message you are getting